# Transformations between isomorphic spaces

Tags: vector-spaces, vector-space-isomorphism

If $T$ is a linear transformation from $R^3\rightarrow{P}_2$ does $T$ have to be one-to-one? In other words, does any transformation between $R^3$ and $P_2$ have to be an isomorphism just because the spaces are isomorphic, or can there be a linear transformation that is not one-to-one?

Comment: The linear transformation $T \ : \ \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{P}_2$ which maps everything to $0$ is not bijective.

Comment: So the transformation doesn't need to be isomorphic just because the spaces are isomorphic?

Comment: Exactly. The spaces being isomorphic means that there exists an ismomorphism, not that all linear transformation are isomorphism.

Comment: Okay –– I understand now. Thank you for your help!